# How to use multidatabase across multiproject in django?

Tags: python, django

I have several django projects to serve different services which have connection to each other (ignore the reason why). To isolate each service, I provide a lib to do the dirty job. The problem is that I can import models from different projects but django maps every model to the database of the running project NOT the project which the model belongs to.

Tried many options but just can't fix it. Again, services should be isolated in each project and can communicate to each other only by lib.

Answer (score 1):

You should setup all the connections needed in your settings and use [database routers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers) for routing the request to the correct database connection, depending on the model.